# How to print option value in html element?

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

i am trying to add an h2 element that shows and updating price based on selected option value.

Here is my current code:

```html
<select name="price">
  <option value="2799"> 1-6 תשלומים</option>
  <option value="3200">12 תשלומים </option>
  <option value="2799"> 36 תשלומים</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Give the close tag </option> for the first option

Comment: its was like this miss click on copy*

Comment: I really don't understand what you are expecting?

Comment: i want that if you choose "option 1" so it show the price in h2 (2799) and if you choose the option 2 its show (3200)

Comment: Then it's easy ...interchange the logic like this..<option value="your_label "> 2799</option>

Comment: yes but i want that the price will be under the box not inside

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can print option value by adding onchange event on it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select name="price" onchange="changePrice()">
            <option value="2600"> 1-6 תשלומים</option>
            <option value="3200">12 תשלומים </option>
            <option value="2799"> 36 תשלומים</option>
        </select>
        <h2 id="id"></h2>
        <script>
            function changePrice() {
                var selector = document.getElementsByName("price")[0];
                var value = selector[selector.selectedIndex].value;
                document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = value;
            }
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", changePrice);
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```